# Python sample from given probablility function

Tags: python, probability

I have a probability function `P(X = x)` and I want to sample from it.
I have found some functions that sample from given list of values/probabilities, but in my case there is "infinite" set of values and probabilities.

My probability tends to zero for both high and low values so I can arbitrarily set some "border" (f.e. 0.000001) and ignore `P(X = x) < border`. That gives me ability to use some function that takes finite array of P(X).

I wonder, there is a simpler way?

Comment: Find the integral/scaled cumulative sum, and map a uniform distribution using that.

Comment: In addition, there are a couple of pre-built random functions in NumPy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html as well as some helper function for the aforementioned approach in SciPy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html

Comment: How is your probability distribution represented?

Comment: It is a function like P(X = m) = 1/m+3 or sth like this